# How to quickly grab specific indices from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, python-2.x

But I don't have the index values, I just have ones in those same indices in a different array. For example, I have

```
a = array([3,4,5,6])
b = array([0,1,0,1])
```

Is there some `NumPy` method than can quickly look at both of these and extract all values from `a` whose indices match the indices of all `1`'s in `b`? I want it to result in:

```
array([4,6])
```

It is probably worth mentioning that my `a` array is multidimensional, while my `b` array will always have values of either `0` or `1`. I tried using `NumPy`'s `logical_and` function, though this returns `ValueError` with `a` and `b` having different dimensions:

```
a = numpy.array([[3,2], [4,5], [6,1]])
b = numpy.array([0, 1, 0])
print numpy.logical_and(a,b)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (3,)
```

Though this method does seem to work if `a` is flat. Either way, the return type of `numpy.logical_and()` is a boolean, which I do not want. Is there another way? Again, in the second example above, the desired return would be

```
array([[4,5]])
```

Obviously I could write a simple loop to accomplish this, I'm just looking for something a bit more concise.

Edit:

This will introduce more constraints, I should also mention that each element of the multidimensional array `a` may be any arbitrary length, that does not match its neighbour.

Comment: How about `a[b.astype(bool)]`?

Comment: I just tried it, thanks. This is slick. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for the multidimensional `a` situation :(

Comment: Add such a multi-dimensional array sample case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use fancy indexing.

```
b == 1
```

will give you a boolean array:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a = array([3,4,5,6])
>>> b = array([0,1,0,1])
>>> b==1
array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

which you can pass as an index to a.

```
>>> a[b==1]
array([4, 6])
```

Demo for your second example:

```
>>> a = array([[3,2], [4,5], [6,1]])
>>> b = array([0, 1, 0])
>>> a[b==1]
array([[4, 5]])
```

Comment: I like this a lot, but it does not seem to work for the arbitrary multi-dimensional case

Comment: @jphollowed It works for your second example `[[3,2], [4,5], [6,1]]` and `[0, 1, 0]` what cases are you having trouble with?

Comment: @ah you are correct, I was making a mistake. This is the most eloquent answer, then

Comment: This is indeed a good method and should be accepted if you find it easiest to work with. It's maybe worth noting that it requires the creation of a new temporary boolean array first, but unless you're working with massive arrays that shouldn't be a problem. Also remember to put the boolean array in the correct axis! e.g. use `a[:, b==1]` to take from axis 1, rather than axis 0.

Comment: I should add that from my experimenting, it seems that if one of your objects is a python listm, and one is a numpy array, this will not work

Comment: @jphollowed you could always cast that list to `array`. The reason it does not work with a python list `lst` is that `lst == 1` will simply return `False`, not a bool array.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`compress`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([3,4,5,6])
>>> b = np.array([0,1,0,1])
>>> a.compress(b)
array([4, 6])
```

You can provide an `axis` argument for multi-dimensional cases:

```
>>> a2 = np.array([[3,2], [4,5], [6,1]])
>>> b2 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
>>> a2.compress(b2, axis=0)
array([[4, 5]])
```

This method will work even if the axis of `a` you're indexing against is a different length to `b`.